# Python POST request code does not work in django

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I have a POST request which works perfectly in normal Python CLI. It returns me a webpage, yes a webpage and then I can simple use Regex to extract some part of it and that's it. However I'm having lots of trouble trying to do the same in Django and show the extracted text on a webpage.

Below are code snippets from my files. Please keep in mind that I'm new to Django & Web.

Here's the **urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.output, name='getINFO')
]
```

Here's the home template **home.html**

```
<body>
        <script>
            var link = '{% url "getINFO" %}';
        </script>

       <button onclick="location.href = link">Submit</button><hr>
       {% if data %}
       <p>{{data}}</p>
       {% endif %}
    </body>
```

Here's the function in **views.py**

```
def output(request):
    
    headers = {
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'Pragma':'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control':'no-cache',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
    'Origin':'https://www.xxxxxx.com',
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Referer':'https://www.xxxxxxx.com',
    'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.9'
    }

    payload = {
    '__VIEWSTATE':'xxx',
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':'xxx',
    '__EVENTVALIDATION':'xxx',
    'MIS':'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'MISB':'xxxx'
    }

    url = 'https://www.xxxxxx.com'
    res = requests.post(url,headers=headers, data=payload)

    price = re.search('style="font-size:X-Large;">(.*?)\/-<\/span>',res.text)

    return render(request,'home.html',{'data':price})
```

The above request works just fine in normal Python CLI and price does indeed have the extracted text which I can then see by printing it onto the console. I want to do the same thing here, print out whatever text price has onto the webpage.

Comment: what is the error you are able to see ?

Comment: @ShreeyanshJain There's no error, it just won't display the extracted text which is stored in "price" upon clicking the button. it simply just loads the same page.